# Pandas: compare huge dataframe with smaller dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, large-data

I have two dataframes I want to compare in pandas, one is too large to fit in memory and the other is smaller and does fit in memory.

```
dfSmall:
cat1    cat2
foo     bar
foo     tiger
foo     spam
bar     spam
(5000 rows)

dfLarge:
cat1    cat2    cat3
foo     dog     green
foo     tiger   blue
foo     snake   green
foo     bird    pink
bar     dog     orange
...
(>1 million rows)
```

I have used dask.dataframe (dd.merge), but it takes a long time and a lot of fiddling, and it seems inefficient as one of my df will fit into memory. I have also used pandas.read_table with a set chunksize, but only to modify the file itself, not to compare it to another file.

The additional complication is I want the output file to only keep rows that match **two** columns - cat1 and cat2. In the above example, the output would just be one line - `foo    cat`, because that's the only line where both columns match. If matching two columns is not possible, I wouldn't mind a solution that can only match on one column, I'd just have to modify the dataframes to combine cat1/cat2 into one column.

```
dfOutput:
cat1    cat2    cat3
foo     tiger   blue
```

Comment: In the above example, the output would be `foo    tiger` (not `foo    cat`), no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`read_table` with chunksize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html), say you first makes a function that merges a chunk with the smaller table:

```
dfSmall = pd.read_table(small_path, ...)

def merge_it(c):
    return dfSmall.merge(c, on=['cat1', 'cat2'], suffixes=('', '_y'))[['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3']]
```

Note that when you merge, pandas will add suffixes on the common columns. The code above says not to add suffixes to the columns of the chunk (that is `''` in the tuple), and to take the columns `'cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3'`.

Then you can concatenate chunk merges of the larger ones, like this:

```
pd.concat([merge_it(c) for c in pd.read_table(large_path, ..., chunksize=100000)])
```

Note that for each chunk, you get the merge of it with the small DataFrame. To get the full result, you need to concatenate the results.

Comment: I will try this! Could you expand on why `suffixes=` and the categories in brackets at the end (the small dataset only has `cat1/cat2`, so is this telling the merge which columns to save in the large dataset? Why use pd.concat with your merge `def` instead of the merge, how does adding that make it possible to merge with the large file? Thanks!

Comment: @Liquidity Added explanations.